# Parse - Unity3D : How to create a user after a Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

'm using the Facebook SDK 6.0 for Unity3D.

After my user accept the connection, I want to save his ID, email etc ... on a Parse database, and have the possibility to get some info from this database for this player (for exemple : the list of unlock levels).

How can I do it ?

I know how create an object, but I want to know, after a connection on Facebook, how to save the user and some details on Parse, without using the Parse login (as on the official Parse tutorial).

I can't understand.

Thank you very very much in advance for your help.

Best regards,

AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving this information in the local ParseUser Object.  Just add custom fields with the necessary information. For more complex solutions you can create a custom parse object to save the information.

https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#users

```
var user = new ParseUser()
{
    Username = "my name",
    Password = "my pass",
    Email = "email@example.com"
};

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user["IsUnlocked"] = true;

Task signUpTask = user.SignUpAsync();
```

and for Facebook there is a special signup method in the ParseFacebookUtils class
https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#fbusers

```
Task<ParseUser> logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(userId, accessToken, tokenExpiration);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But when a user is loged with facebook, no password is needed normally. But parse need one .. :(

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask an other question ? If I want now to set properties for this user how can I do that ? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: The ParseUser is a subclass of ParseObject. You may modify the ParseUser just like any other ParseObject after creation.

https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#objects

Comment: Hi,So if i do that : 

private Task<ParseUser> _logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(userId.Value, accessToken.Value, System.DateTime.Now);

   ParseUser user = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
   user ["className"] = "theDatas";
   
   var saveTask = user.SaveAsync();

It should work , right ? 

It's not the case .. :'(

Comment: Define "not working" are you getting an exception ? is it not saving ? Did you sign up first ?